# how to put AMI name in packer manifest

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer, hashicorp-packer

I would like to get the AMI name into the packer manifest.  I understand how to get this for the AMI id but its different for the name.
I have:

```
data "amazon-ami" "ubuntu" {
  filters = {
     name = "ubuntu-minimal/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-minimal-*"
     root-device-type    = "ebs"
     virtualization-type = "hvm"
  }
  most_recent = true
  region      = "us-east-1"
}
source "amazon-ebs" "ui" {
  ami_name      = "my-ami-${formatdate("YYYY-MM-DD-hhmmss", timestamp())}"
  instance_type = "t3.small"
  region        = "us-east-1"
  source_ami    = "${data.amazon-ami.ubuntu.id}"
  ssh_pty       = true
  ssh_username  = "ubuntu"
}
build {
  sources = ["source.amazon-ebs.ui"]
  
  post-processor "manifest" {
    output = "manifest.json"
    strip_path = true
    custom_data = {
      version = "${source.ami_name}"
    }
  }
}
```

The error I am getting is `Unsupported attribute; This object does not have an attribute named "ami_name".`
According to this: https://www.packer.io/docs/templates/hcl_templates/blocks/source it looks like the only attributes I do have access to are name and type.  How can I get the `ami_name` into the manifest?

Comment: You would probably have to set `name` equal to `ami_name` in either block and then access with `source.name` or `build.name`, although that could end up becoming unclear if the template or manifests expand to more sources and builds.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Can you please provide example where to set ```name```

Answer (score 6):

I don't think you can get the name like that but you can put it in a local and then use it in both your builder and in the manifest like this:

```
locals { 
  my_ami_name = "my-ami-${formatdate("YYYY-MM-DD-hhmmss", timestamp())}"
}
data "amazon-ami" "ubuntu" {
  filters = {
     name = "ubuntu-minimal/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-minimal-*"
     root-device-type    = "ebs"
     virtualization-type = "hvm"
  }
  owners      = ["099720109477"]
  most_recent = true
  region      = "us-east-1"
}
source "amazon-ebs" "ui" {
  ami_name      = local.my_ami_name
  instance_type = "t3.small"
  region        = "us-east-1"
  source_ami    = "${data.amazon-ami.ubuntu.id}"
  ssh_pty       = true
  ssh_username  = "ubuntu"
}
build {
  sources = ["source.amazon-ebs.ui"]
  
  post-processor "manifest" {
    output = "manifest.json"
    strip_path = true
    custom_data = {
      version = local.my_ami_name
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I like that, thanks!